# Issue with plyer library of python when creating a executable using pyinstaller

Tags: python, windows

I am trying to generate a notification in windows using plyer library in python. It works fine when the python script is run. But when I try to create an executable file using pyinstaller and run the executable I keep getting this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "site-packages\plyer\utils.py", line 96, in _ensure_obj
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'plyer.platforms'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "in_time.py", line 131, in <module>
  File "site-packages\plyer\facades\notification.py", line 84, in notify
  File "site-packages\plyer\facades\notification.py", line 90, in _notify
NotImplementedError: No usable implementation found!
```

This is the snippet of the code

```py
from plyer import notification

    notification.notify(
       title='9 hours Completed',
       message='You have successfully completed 9hrs for the day',
       app_name='In Time App',
       app_icon='Time3.ico'
    )
```

Answer (score 13):

When creating the executable with pyinstaller, add this to the command:

```
--hidden-import plyer.platforms.win.notification
```

Comment: one year after still the same, +1

Comment: 2 years after still the same :)

Answer (score 1):

I am using Windows and the solution with hiddenimports didn't work for me.

There's an other solution by copying the plyer package from python site_packages to the application directory as described here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/64448486/11362192

The copying of this package can also be automated. To do this, add the original path to the plyer package as datas to the spec file:

```
site_packages_dir = 'C:/Python/Python310/Lib/site-packages/'

a = Analysis(
   ...
   datas=[(site_packages_dir+'plyer', './plyer')],
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

add following hidden import to spec file

```
a = Analysis(
   ...
   hiddenimports=['plyer.platforms.win.notification'],
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pyinstaller --onefile --hidden-import plyer.platforms.linux.notification filename.py
```

if you are using linux

```
plyer.platforms.win.notification
```

if you are using win
There are also ios, macos, android platforms available so if you are using that, you may want to use those. If it doesn't work then you may want to check the plyer.platforms.<your_flatform> directory and see if notifications.py is existing or not.