# problem with plyer when using PyInstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have made a timer, when the time is up, it shows a notification using the module `plyer` but when I turn it into an executable with pyinstaller using the command `pyinstaller timer.pyw` and run it, the notification does not show and the window just crashes. I think it's because that `pyinstaller` does not support `plyer`. I've tried using the `--hidden-import` option but it still does not work. how do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just went to python's site-packages folder, for me it was `c:\python\Lib\site-packages\` and copied the plyer folder to the PyInstaller directory.